Can you create hotspots on an animated SVG background?
Is it possible to create multiple hotspots on an animated SVG background?
I created the animated SVG on SVGator and I thought I could add the hotspots in After Effects. However, it has been difficult to even import SVG to AE. Are there other tools or apps I can use to accomplish this?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is a hotspot? Present an example of the animation you did and then either explain or give an example on what a hotspot is. We often assume that this is going to be used on a web page, is that also the case here?
